# Laravel 5.2 left join one to many only row with column of highest value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to do a left join using eloquent on a one to many relationship. I would only like to get the row with the highest value in the sort_order column.

So far my query looks like this:

```
Package::select('packages.*')
        ->leftJoin('package_routes', 'package_routes.package_id', '=', 'packages.id')
        ->leftJoin('package_route_items', function($join){
            $join->on('package_route_items.package_route_id', '=', 'package_routes.id')
                ->where(???);
        })->...//do more stuff to query here
```

I'm stuck on the where clause, if I should even be using a where at all.

Comment: Please provide your table definition as from your question its unclear from which table you need highest row and which table has `sort_order` column

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know all the query where conditions i'll try to simplify (you will probably have to adjust column names and syntax

add `use DB;` at beginning of your controller/model

```
$data = DB::table('packages')
->select('packages.*, package_route_items.company_id, package_routes.company_id')
    ->join('package_routes', 'package_routes.package_id', '=', 'packages.id')
    ->join('package_route_items.package_route_id', '=', 'package_routes.id')
    ->orderBy('packages.value_column', 'DESC')->first();
```

That is what i have understand so far from your description. It's not tested but i think it should work with probably minor editing.

Similar question like yours is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388664/laravel-join-with-3-tables), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842977/laravel-eloquent-and-multiple-joins) (hope it helps you even more than mine answer).

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::orderBy()` unfortunately

Comment: Ah apologies, I've also edited my question to make my intentions clear. I need to carry on adding joins to the query and then eventually order by something else. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, can u elaborate a bit about tables and desired output or maybe some info so i can help you with making proper query?

Comment: Sure, so I was originally creating an eloquent query but now I need to be able to order the whole thing on a company name. Now the company itself is a foreign key in `package_route_items`, and I need to get the last `package_route_items.company_id` in the list in order to see the packages final destination.

So the schema is Packages > has one PackageRoute > has many PackageRouteItems > has one company_id

I also need to get another company_id on PackageRoute (the start point) and a few other bits of meta data from the Package.

Comment: To add to that, I'm first making the joins like you can see in the question, and then once I have ordered them correctly I'm hydrating the models with a `->with(...relationships here...)`