# how can i write sql query with many inner join in eloquent( eager loading) using relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this sql query which works fine, how can i write this in eloquent( eager loading) using relationships, not joins.

```
SELECT ads.id,ads.name,u.name,country_translates.name,city_translate.name,category_translates.name
    FROM ads
    INNER JOIN users u ON ads.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN cities ON ads.city_id = cities.id
    INNER JOIN country_translates ON cities.country_id = country_translates.country_id
    INNER JOIN city_translate ON ads.city_id = city_translate.city_id
    INNER JOIN category_translates ON ads.category_id = category_translates.category_id
    WHERE country_translates.language_id = 2 AND city_translate.language_id = 2 AND category_translates.language_id = 2
```

Comment: if you joins are all relations and are set up correctly, you could use `whereHas` : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842977/laravel-eloquent-and-multiple-joins

Comment: Could you please post the models you are using. It would be impossible to answer this without seeing relationship and model names. Also have you tried to write this in eloquent?